# BigQuery Transfer: Google Ads (formerly AdWords): Transfer job is successful but no data

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I try to setup transfer with following configuration:

```
Source: Google Ads (formerly AdWords)
Destination dataset: app_google_ads
Schedule (UTC): every day 08:24
Notification Cloud Pub/Sub topic: None
Email notifications: None
Data source details
Customer ID: xxx-xxx-xxxx
Exclude removed/disabled items: None
```

I got no error during transfer but my dataset is empty, why?

```
12:02:00 PM Summary: succeeded 72 jobs, failed 0 jobs.  
12:01:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cdace41-0000-2184-a73e-001a11435098 (table p_VideoConversionStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully  
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cdace37-0000-2184-a73e-001a11435098 (table p_HourlyAccountStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully    
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cd88a2b-0000-2117-b857-089e082679e4 (table p_HourlyCampaignStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully   
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cd0ba27-0000-2c7c-aed0-f40304362f4a (table p_AudienceBasicStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully    
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cd907f8-0000-2e16-a735-089e082678cc (table p_KeywordStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully  
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cd88a32-0000-2117-b857-089e082679e4 (table p_ShoppingProductConversionStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully    
12:00:04 PM Job 77454333956:adwords_5cce5c09-0000-28bd-86d3-f4030437b908 (table p_AdBasicStats_2495318378$20190502) completed successfully  

etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I have AdBlocked enabled in my browser. So it prevent me to see google ads tables in my dataset. So I turn off it and it works!